# Analytic geometry question - finding an equation of a line in 3D

Tags: analytic-geometry

I need to find the equation of the line that intersects perpendicularly the line:
$$
\frac{x+1}{2}=-y=\frac{z-2}{3}
$$
and passes through : $(2,3,1)$.

So I know that the line should be of the form:
$$
(2,3,1)+t (\ell , m ,n)
$$
where:
$(\ell , m ,n) \cdot (2,-1,3)=0 $
but this gives me only one constraint on my parameters . How can I find all three of them?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You have not used the fact that the lines intersect.

Comment: Let $\vec{ON}$ be the foot of perpendicular of $\vec{OA}=(2,3,1)$ to the line. ($\vec{ON}$ lies on the known line). $\vec{AN} \cdot (2,-1,3)=0$.

Comment: egreg: I can imagine only one such line. 
@Nicholas : I am sorry, but I can't see what you have just written . Are you trying to show  me an arbitrary way to choose the vector $(\ell,m,n)$ ? 
Thanks!